# serialize dictionary in field for a rest API end point django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer where I want to render a dictionary, I am also converting that dictionary to a JSON format, but I am getting the following error:

Object of type Job is not JSON serializable.

The code looks like this:

```
jobs_by_hour = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
 def get_jobs_by_hour(self, obj):
    jobs = Job.objects.annotate(hour=ExtractHour('dt_start'))
    res = defaultdict(lambda: [])
    for x in jobs:
        res[x.hour].append(x)
    return json.dumps(res)
```

I am a newb at this and I don't know how to fix this issue, any help is welcome. ultimately, with this dictionary i want to display the data grouped by the hour, so i get 24 lists of jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the queryset object. You need to append serialized data. Something like this should work.

```
 def get_jobs_by_hour(self, obj):
    jobs = Job.objects.annotate(hour=ExtractHour('dt_start'))
    res = defaultdict(lambda: [])
    for x in jobs:
        res[x.hour].append(JobSerializer(x).data)
    return json.dumps(res)
```

Add a field `hour` in your default `JobSerializer`.

Comment: well, that works! but the problem now is that i am getting that data repeated in every object and i dont want that, how do i solve this?

Comment: Can't know that from the code you have provided. May be you need to provide your viewsets and serializers.

Comment: oh it wont be necessary actually, I solved the problem, I had to create a separate Serializer for it :) But thank you so much, this part of the answer doesn't really relate to the main question I asked anyway :p

Comment: yeah, i have been posting some questions related to this indeed :)